# Locale-gen segmentation fault

Tags: locale, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to generate locales, but locale-gen (localedef?) segfaults.

```
# sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
Generating locales...
  en_US.ISO-8859-1... /usr/sbin/locale-gen: line 177: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
/usr/sbin/locale-gen: line 243:  3809 Segmentation fault      localedef $no_archive -i $input -c -f $charset $locale_alias $locale
failed
  en_US.UTF-8... /usr/sbin/locale-gen: line 177: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
/usr/sbin/locale-gen: line 243:  3836 Segmentation fault      localedef $no_archive -i $input -c -f $charset $locale_alias $locale
failed
Generation complete.
```

In `top` I see `localedef -i en_US -c -f ISO-8859-1 en_US` taking up `8000G` of virtual memory, then some huge number without even `G` suffix and then segfault.

System has `1G` memory and `512MB` SWAP, but memory is barely used (`130MB` at peak of generation).

System data:

```
root@docs:~# uname -a
Linux docs 2.6.32-042stab078.28 #1 SMP Mon Jul 8 10:17:22 MSK 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

root@docs:~# cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS"

root@docs:~# dpkg-query --show glibc*
glibc-2.13-1
glibc-doc

root@docs:~# sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
...skipped...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have these lines in your `/etc/default/locale` file:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

The `LC_CTYPE` setting is wrong, since "UTF-8" is not a valid locale name. Also, it makes no sense to set all those variables; I would recommend that you simply remove the `LC_ALL` and `LC_CTYPE` lines.

(I saw something similar recently. It would be interesting to know how that `LC_CTYPE=UTF-8` statement ended up there in the first place.)

Comment: Actually I have only those:
    LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
    LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Comment: Setting LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 and then `sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8`, then `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` helped!  Thanks!

Comment: Oops, was running commands on wrong machine. Setting LC_CTYPE explicitly didn't help, still segfault :(

Comment: Don't bother with locale-gen and dpkg-reconfigure. Your problem is that LC_CTYPE is incorrectly set somewhere, apparently somewhere else but `/etc/default/locale`. Maybe some of your config files in `$HOME` contains the incorrect statement, such as `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`.